# How To Prevent Window Close Event Using HostListener In Angular 2+

Tags: events, angular5, onbeforeunload

I am using HostListener to get window close event and try to prevent the event.

I imported HostListener First and Used this code. But, I couldn't prevent the window close event.

```
  import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
   onWindowClose(event: any): void {

       this.doSomething();

   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent window close event for separate component, using **HostListener**.

*First Import* HostListener in your component

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

And, Use this code to prevent window close.

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
   onWindowClose(event: any): void {
    // Do something

     event.preventDefault();
     event.returnValue = false;

  }
```

Now, Your event was prevented.

Comment: I have used the same, but it's not working for me and no error is showing

Comment: @pal  :: In which component you include that beforeunload event ? .Open that particular component in your browser. Then Close the Browser Tab. It will show you the alert popup.! Try it again. If you have any doubt let me know.  Or Can you show your code on email?

Comment: here you are talking about two component?

Comment: @pal :: Yes. In my project, I used this event for form submission. If user enters the form component, then the user filled the details, and then the user try to close that tab, I will check the form first. If there is any value he/she enters. Then I prevent the tab close. Otherwise the tab will close. I used this for only one component. If you want to prevent tab close for whole application you can write some script on index.html file(Without Host Listener) , or your can also achieve it by adding host Listener by each component.